# UI Tabbed with each Tab has a different View/ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, telerik, mvvm-light

In my project, I have to create an administration interface with a menu. At each click on this menu, a new tab will open.
Because I am in MVVM, each tab is a different ViewModel (which inherit from the same ViewModel base class) and a different View.

I have defined an `ItemTemplate` for the header but it's common for all tabs instead of the content is not.

My `TabControl` is binded to an `ObservableCollection` of ViewModel base class.

So, how can I load the right view in interface according to its ViewModel?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx from Josh Smith (he's kind of an MVVM guru). In the example application, he does exactly what you are looking for. And it's a very interesting read to get into MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

I finally solved my issue with an other way :

I use the RadTabControl (from telerik) and it exposes a property named ContentTemplateSelector which is binded to a class who extends DataTemplateSelector.

ItemsSource of RadTabControl is binded to an ObservableCollection of TabViewModelBase. At each time, i add a new tab, my DataTemplateSelector base class choose the right view according to the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828661/silverlight-4-making-closeable-tabitems/4830314#4830314) is my answer to a similar question where you can found an extended TabControl and an example of code.

So now I focus on your particular implementation.
In this example a `TabControl` is bound to the `Items` property, a menu List - to the `MenuItems` property.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(){ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel>
                         {
                             new TabItemViewModel("Tab 1", OnItemRequestClose),
                             new TabItemViewModel("Tab item 2", OnItemRequestClose)
                         };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MenuItems { get; set; }

    public string CurrentMenuItem
    {
        get { return currentMenuItem; }
        set 
        { 
            currentMenuItem = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMenuItem");
            this.OnMenuChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public void OnItemRequestClose(TabItemViewModel item)
    {
        this.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentMenuItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

You can use a command bound to the `SelectionChanged` event, but my solution is more universal.

An implementation of the method `OnMenuChanged`:

```
private void OnMenuChanged()
{
    if(this.CurrentMenuItem == "Item 1")
    {
        var addItem = new TabItemViewModel("Item 1", OnItemRequestClose);
        addItem.Content = new SomeView() { DataContext = new SomeViewModel() };
        this.Items.Add(addItem);
    }
    //and so on, and so forth
}
```

I used this solution in a real-world application, so you can be sure that it works without problems.